# Authenticate Auth0 using cypress with in-browser cross domain login

Tags: javascript, cypress, auth0

I am trying to log into my app using Cypress. The flow is...

- A user visits my site
- I notice they are not authenticated
- I redirect them to auth0 to authenticate
- Auth0 sends me a code via callback and they are redirected back to the page

When I try this flow with the following Cypress code...

```
const fillLogin = async () => {
  cy.log("Filling login");
  cy.get("#username")
    .should("be.visible")
    .type(testUser());
  cy.get("#password")
    .should("be.visible")
    .type(testPassword());
  cy.get("button[name=\"action\"]")
    .should("be.visible")
    .click();

  return cy.get(".main-container")
    .should("be.visible");
};
```

Everything works until it gets ready to redirect back to the `/callback` and it just freezes. The url it gets stuck on is `/authorize/resume?state=...`.

I think it might be because the authentication is in a domain other than the actual webapp domain.